# React Navigation: Why to use methods on the navigation object instead of using action creators and dispatch (i.e. CommonActions)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In the [official docs of react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x#action-creators) it says:

> It's highly recommended to use the methods on the navigation object instead of using action creators and `dispatch`. It should only be used for advanced use cases.

**But why is that?** I didn't find any explanation for this strong recommendation in the react-navigation docs.

With `CommonActions` (or `NavigationActions` in react-navigation smaller equal 4.x) I can nicely create navigation functions which I can access from anywhere without the need of passing a `navigation` prop around. And I didn't encounter issues with it which I could relate to it being a `CommonAction` instead of a part of the `navigation` prop - even in more complex scenarios with many screens and special routing arrangements.

Comment: I now also found the following reason in another part of the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#handling-initialization: Do not use this method when you have access to a navigation prop or useNavigation since it will behave differently, and many helper methods specific to screens won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons:

- Methods on the `navigation` object are strictly type-checked, i.e. if you use something like TypeScript or Flow, you'll get errors if you pass incorrect values, it's way more relaxed with action objects, which will only log error during runtime.
- When a method exists, it means the related navigator is definitely rendered. You can't call `openDrawer` if you don't have a drawer, but you can call `dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())`.
- It's more typing `navigate('Home')` vs `dispatch(CommonActions.navigate('Home'))`

> without the need of passing a navigation prop around

Not sure how action creators help with that, but you could just use `useNavigation`

Comment: `useNavigation` fulfills a similar purpose as `CommonActions` in that it offers the use of a `navigation` prop without the need to manually pass it down to the component. Given this, `useNavigation` also has the disadvantage of the second reason you mentioned I guess.